# dealloc gets not called for control

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiwebview

I have a sub class of UIWebView and use it in a view controller.

```
CViewController *controller = [[CViewController alloc] init];
self.webView = controller;
[controller release];
```

Now in my view controller dealloc gets called and I call `[_webView release]`
but the dealloc in my UIWebView subclass gets never called and the memory usage raise on every time I put one view controller on the stack and never gets released after pop from the stack.
Also I can see all my windows in the Safari Development Tools, so they are never be released.
I check the retainCount (I know its not very useful) but it told me after the assignment to my property the retainCount is 3? (Property is nonatomic, retain)

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2740404?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I use instruments and everytime I navigate from my tableview to this controller my live bytes gets up 300-500kb mainly in CFData.
And as far as I see after my dealloc in my view controller gets called the retain count of my uiwebview should be 0 so its should get called dealloc for this class.#

Comment: Use ARC. There's no reason not to unless you are still supporting iOS 3 (which would be a mistake).

Comment: Yah, you should be using ARC.

Answer (score 1):

The `retainCount` of 3 is a red herring;  a useless distraction.  http://www.whentouseretaincount.com and all that.

Since you have a repeatedly leak scenario, [Heapshot analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) should help pinpoint exactly why the memory is sticking around.

However, you may not need to go that far.  If your app only has one UIWebView, then you should simply be able to configure the Allocations instrument to only track live objects and to track retain/release events.  With that, filter the list of objects in memory down to the UIWebView and click through to the list of retain/release events associated with the object.   The extra retain(s) will be found there.

That, however, may be a symptom and not the cause.  The cause could be caching gone wrong or could be some other object that isn't properly being released that is hanging on to the web view.